# Ubuntu and Zoom seem to conflict

Tags: zoom-meeting

I have to regularly reinstall Zoom on my Ubuntu laptop. Maybe every week. I get an update request saying 'Your app version needs to be 5.10.0 (2450) or higher to join this meeting. Please update to continue.'

This is odd, since I have downloaded maybe 100 times the same version in the period of less than 6 months. There are no changes in the version. I have asked friends who use windows as operating system. They say they have updated Zoom only once in the last 12 months. So this might be due to Ubuntu.

What should I do? Often, even if I download again the same version, uninstall the last one, install the new download, I get the same update requirement. It is really very demanding to need to do all these steps shortly before a Zoom meeting.

I will appreciate any comment and help.

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Thanks,

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135141/discussion-on-question-by-user249018-ubuntu-and-zoom-seem-to-conflict).

Comment: I use Firefox. This was the reason. I did the the same with Chrome and everything went fine. Many thanks to all of you.